# Ethers.js websocket Provider timing out

Tags: ethers.js

```
    provider.on('block', async (blocknr) =>
    {
        console.log(blocknr)
     }
```

Im using this to listen to new blocks and search for new smart contracts to simulate them.
My problem is, that the connection times out without any error. just stops receiving new blocks and times out. I tryed to add a function which compares the blocknumbers every 20 sec and reset the provider, but that does not solve my problem.

```
setInterval(async () => {
        if (timeoutBlock === currentBlock) {
            console.log("No new Blocks in 20 sec, reconnecting...");
            provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(config.mainws);
        }
        timeoutBlock = currentBlock;
    }, 20000); // sec checks
```

Comment: What provider are you using?